# How to ask if someone is ready

Tags: set-phrases

I think I can ask something like もう学校に行く用意はできてるの for "Are you ready to go to school yet".
I was wondering what is the most natural way to simply ask "Are you ready yet?". E.g. the wife is in the bathroom and you are just about to go out to the movies together. Can I just shorten this to もう用意ができてるの. To me it sounds formal. More like "did you make preparations yet" rather than "are you ready (to go)".
Maybe I can just ask もうできてるの？ Would that be understood?

Comment: I think 用意 is mostly used to prepare/arrange/organize something for (usually) someone else...

Comment: ^ 「用意」でいいと思いますが・・・。（ちなみに私や家族は「(もう)用意できた？」以外に「もう出れる？」(←ら抜き言葉ですが)「もう行ける？」とか「まだ？」とか言います）

Comment: Related: [What is the difference in usage between 準備　用意 and 覚悟](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/9334/78).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the most natural way to simply ask "Are you ready yet?".

A quick search on [Weblio](http://ejje.weblio.jp/sentence/content/are+you+ready) suggests [準備](http://ejje.weblio.jp/sentence/content/%E6%BA%96%E5%82%99) like in　`もう準備はいいか?` or `もう準備できた?`.

Of course there are other ways in which "are you ready" may appear and it will depend greatly on context. Asking a student if he/she is ready for an exam can be done with either `試験の準備はいいか?` as well as `試験、大丈夫?`. The former implies there are things to be arranged beforehand, while the latter asks if the student is confident.

Comment: I never realised the 英語例文 tab existed in Weblio. That should greatly improve my life. Thanks.